# RecyclerView is showing nothing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have some items in my adapter but nothing is shown in the RecyclerView.

**Adapter**

```
public class WorkOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WorkOrderViewHolder> {

    private List<WorkOrder> orders = new LinkedList<>();

    public void setData(List<WorkOrder> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

    @Override
    public WorkOrderViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_workorder, parent, false);
        return new WorkOrderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WorkOrderViewHolder holder, int position) {
        WorkOrder order = orders.get(position);
        holder.bind(order);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orders.size();
    }

}
```

**ViewHolder**

```
public class WorkOrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView title;
    private TextView description;
    private TextView date;

    public WorkOrderViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title_textview);
        description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description_textview);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
    }

    public void bind(WorkOrder order) {
        title.setText("Test");
        description.setText("Test");
        date.setText("Test");
    }
}
```

**Activity (Using AndroidAnnotations)**

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_workorders)
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.activity_workorders)
public class WorkOrdersActivity extends ToolbarActivity {

    @ViewById(R.id.orders_recyclerview)
    RecyclerView ordersList;

    List<WorkOrder> orders = new LinkedList<>();
    private WorkOrderAdapter adapter;

    {
        adapter = new WorkOrderAdapter();
        orders.add(new WorkOrder());
        orders.add(new WorkOrder());
        orders.add(new WorkOrder());
        adapter.setData(orders);
    }

    @AfterViews
    public void initViews() {
        ordersList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you setting the adapter to the recyclerview? What data are you setting as data?

Comment: I have added the activity code.

Comment: plz share logcat.................

Comment: There is no error. The list is just empty.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please add the [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html) to the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and try again

```
ordersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
ordersList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: happy coding..!! Accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: Here's how to do it in XML:
`<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView ... android:orientation="vertical" app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>`